# How to get Javascript class fields and functions

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

Is there any way to get functions and fields from JavaScript class without initializing an object of that class?

```
var SimpleClass = function() {
    this.type = 'singleClassType';
    this.getType = function() {
        var self = this;
        return self.type;
    }
}
```

I want to get type field (which is like static).

I can do something like this, but I really don`t want to use prototype of class:

```
SimpleClass.prototype.type = 'customName'
```

Here is the code I use:

```
var Class1 = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
}
Class1.prototype.type = 'class1';

var Class2 = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
}
Class2.prototype.type = 'class2';

var Class3 = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
}
Class3.prototype.type = 'class3';

var Class4 = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
}
Class4.prototype.type = 'class4';

var xml = {},
xmlText = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
    generateObjects();
});

function generateObjects() {
    for(var i=1;i<5;i++){
        if(typeof eval('Class'+i).prototype.getHtml === 'undefined'){
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'xml',
                url: 'file.xml',
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    xmlText = data;
                    addClassData();
                }
            });
            function addClassData(){
                xml['"'+eval('Class'+i).prototype.type+'"'] = xmlText;
            }
            eval('Class'+i).prototype.getHtml = function(){
                var self = this;
                return xml['"'+self.type+'"'];
            }
        }
        var kl =  eval('Class'+i),
            obj = new kl(i);
        console.log(obj.getHtml());
    }
}
```

Comment: I use Mootools to create classes, so I can use initialize method to change property.type. But as I said, I`m looking for another way to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to get functions and fields from JavaScript class without initializing an object of that class?

No. Unless you [decompile the function](http://perfectionkills.com/state-of-function-decompilation-in-javascript/), parse the JS code and look for property assignments.

> I can do something like this, but I really don't want to use prototype of class:

There's nothing wrong with using the prototype if this field is supposed to be shared amongst all instances of the class.

If by "static" you mean that it's rather a class member than an instance member, you can put properties directly on the constructor as well:

```
var SimpleClass = function() {
    this.getType = function() {
        return SimpleClass.type;
        // alternatively, something like `this.constructor.type`
        // but only if you understand when this works and when not
    }
}
SimpleClass.type = 'singleClassType';
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the property/field like this:

```
var SimpleClass = function(){
    this.type = 'singleClassType';
    this.getType = function(){
        var self = this;
        return self.type;
    }
}
SimpleClass["type"] = 'customName';
alert(SimpleClass["type"]);
```

should work too. Have a look at [this MDN article - property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Have a look at [this MDN article - Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for more thorough information about OOP concepts using JavaScript in order to avoid the problem that @PaulS pointed out in his comment.

Comment: This won't be inherited by instances (unless you add and go via _constructor_)

Comment: Question was about getting all fields and functions not only that one e.g type field.

Comment: @pasty That post from SO shows how to iterate through an instance of class. About topic question: You are right!